# Creating Global Map Java

Tags: java

I would like to have a global `HashMap <String, String>` available to my whole project.

The hashmap will remain the same throughout the whole project, so it only needs to be instatiated once. My idea was to have it in a `Utils` class and have a static public class like so:

```
public static String  getValue(String key){
    return map.get(key);
}
```

The problem is, I don't want to have to run code to fill the hashmap with the Strings everytime I call `getValue`. So, where do I instantiate the code?

If I could fill the hashmap similar to:

```
HashMap hm = {{Key, Value}, {Key, Value}......}
```

It could then be global to the utils class and would possibly work.

Comment: Does anything speak against a singleton class holding the Map?

Comment: My first thought is not to have a global map in the first place. My second is that you haven't told us anything about where you *do* want to populate the map...

Comment: No there is not, but I am unsure how to create a singleton

Comment: Please provide more information as people above have specified. Additionally - if your hash map should be the same throughout the whole project you need to make it 'final'.

Comment: I would like the global Map because many classes are required to use it

Comment: [first link in google on searching for 'java singleton enum pattern'](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instantiate it in a static block in the same Utils class.

```
static {
   // init code
}
```

Also you may want to look at the Singleton design pattern as an alternative to keeping static things (class, fields) as suggested here.

I assume your whole app/project is loaded by a single ClassLoader so you
don't need to worry about static block called multiple times or Singleton
objects instantiated multiple times (you want it instantiated just once).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Joshua Bloch's "single element enum type" method, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008912/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-java). If your map should be immutable, consider an [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) from the guava library.

Answer (score 0):

```
package pairtest;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Util {

    private static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    private static Util instance = new Util();

    private Util() {
    }

    public static Util getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static String getValue(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public static void add(String[][] pairs) {
        for(String[] pair : pairs) {
            map.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }
    }

    public static void add(String[] keys, String[] values) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
            map.put(keys[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
}


package pairtest;

public class PairTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arg = {{"key", "value"}, {"key", "value"}, {"key", "value"}};
        Util.add(arg);
    }
}
```