# Unique java objects - different behaviour in run and debug

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that relies on objects being unique. I work with the same object in 2 places, and when an update is done in one place, this should be reflected in the other.

If I debug the program (in eclipse), everything works. My 2 object references both point at the same object (`ojbect1==object2` returns `true`). If I run exactly the same program (in eclipse), there are different objects in both references (same comparison shows `false`).

This object is instantiated multiple times, but one of those instances is saved in a TreeMap and picked up later. However, when I pick it up, sometimes (as described above) it's a different object, which does not hold any changes made to the original object in the meantime.

Does anybody have an idea why this is?

I cannot replicate the problem in a smaller scope so unfortunately I can't post code here.

Comment: So, is the problem only happening when you run it outside of eclipse? or only when you run it in release mode?

Comment: Object.hashCode() isn't reliable for checking uniqueness (==, not .equals()) in a debugger. Use System.identityHashCode(). It's almost right.

Comment: Are you sure your hashCode() isn't the culprit??

Comment: It isn't just hasCode(), the behaviour is also different. If I make a change to the object in place 1, I see the change in place 2 *when I debug*, but I don't see it running exactly the same code *when I run*

Comment: If you want to check an object on hashCode you must override hashCode and equals..

Comment: OK the hasCode() is clearly confusing. I've changed my question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found out the issue was multithreading. Apparently, I was calling the method that 'saved' the object I needed to share multiple times in multiple threads (once where I needed it, and once in a validation routine that runs whenever the user inputs). If the validation thread was activated between my main thread saving the object and picking it up again later, the saved object reference was overwritten. In debug mode, I ran my program step by step, so the other threads had either finished already, or were stalled by the debugger (not sure how this works in eclipse). The fix was to ensure I only saved the object when I needed it, by only allowing this 'saved' object to be written from the place where I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `Object.hashCode()` as a key in a Map because it is not guaranteed to be unique.

Is there something in your object that uniquely identifies it?  If so, then use that as the key.  If not, then create a synthetic key (for example, by incrementing a counter and storing the value in the object).

Comment: I'm not using hashCode() as a key, sorry if my question raised this confusion. I just use hashCode() in a System.out to see if my 2 references are pointing to the same object or not.

Comment: Are you certain that the key you're using is unique?

Comment: I'm using 3 different values of an Enum as key. Still, even if they weren't, you'd expect the same behaviour in run mode than in debug mode ...

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need your program to have a single instance of a given class, you should implement a Singleton pattern.

The recommended way to do this since java 5 is to define an enum type with only one element, something like:

```
public enum MyEnum { 
  MY_SINGLETON_INSTANCE;

  // business logic, etc.

 }
```

This is (at least according to Josh Bloch ;) ) the easiest and safest way to ensure your object instance is unique, doesn't matter what you do.

Here is a broader and more complete discussion on this topic:

[Implementing the singleton pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008912/implementing-the-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Comment: I'm using multiple instances of this object, but want to share one of those instances in multiple places. The enum will not allow this (having multiple instances).

Comment: I am very sorry, I misunderstood you.  Probably jdigital's idea is worth having a look at